Do I need to use Parallel Routes in Next.js for specific route optimization?
I’m working on a T3 stack project using next.js 14 with app router and am considering using Parallel Routes for a specific route to optimize the user experience and performance. However, I’m unsure if this approach is necessary for my case or if it would offer any tangible benefits.
Image of route

so on this route I have an navigation "course details, modules, mentors and rules". The data for this route comes from database. During changing this navigation the first section of the route remains the same. I see some videos about parallel routes but I am not sure do I need them for this specific scenario or not. Can someone give me an advice do I need it or not? or will it be better to do it using just params?
